# No Nontrivial Homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am working through an example in Hungerford. In this example, he asserts that it's not difficult to show that the only homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}$, regarded as an additive group, to $S_3$ is the trivial homomorphism. I am having trouble seeing this. Treat $\Bbb{Q}$ as an additive group, and let $G$ be some group (written multiplicatively). If $f : \Bbb{Q} \to G$ a homomorphism, I believe that $f(p/q) = f(1)^{-pq}$, so that the homomorphism is determined by how it maps $1$ (at least is what I proved on my own; it may be wrong). In our case $G = S_3$. If $f(1)= e$, then $f$ is the trivial homomorphism. If $f(1) \neq e$, then...

Not sure what to do at this point. I could use a hint.

Comment: $S_3$ can be replaced by any finite group here. The point is that $f(1)$ must be divisible, meaning that it has $n^{th}$ roots for all $n$; now show that the only divisible element of any finite group is the identity.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hmm...I wonder if Hungerford had something else in mind, since this example comes before any mention of divisibility

Comment: It is not trivially true that if $f(1)=e$ then $f(x)=e$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q$. You need an argument to show that also $f(1/2)=e$, In particular, it is not true if you have an infinite group rather than $S_3$. For example, $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ with the natural homomorphism has $f(1)=e$ and $f(1/2)\neq e.$

Comment: You don't need to know what divisibility is to use the concept, it's just the cleanest way to organize the proof mentally.

Comment: Yeah, my answer is essentially an elaboration without reference to divisibility.

Comment: And it is not true that $f(p/q)=f(1)^{-pq}$. That's just plain wrong. It is true that $f(p/q)^q=f(1)^p.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $G$ is a finite group and $\phi:\mathbb Q\to G$ then for any $r$:

$$\phi(r)=\phi\left(\frac{r}{|G|}\right)^{|G|}=e$$

because for each $g\in G$, $g^{|G|}=e$.